# Unity3D vs Java3D

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

Hello, I am a Java Programmer and i want to learn Java3D but Unity3D looks more Advanced than Java3D like Unity3D is more lively, more Alive than Java3D.I would like to ask if Java3D can do exactly as Unity3D or even more.

Comment: This is off-topic http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unity is a game engine with tools that support it. Java3D is an old 3d graphics library that's no longer supported. So the two are two quite different beasts. Unity3D can do what Java3D can do and more, because it's more of a set of tools and an engine versus just a graphics library. Also, you might want to look into the new JavaFX 3D features.

Answer (score 1):

`Java3D` is a community project now, and I think it is not very active. `JavaFX` seems to have very impressive 3D api, and it is under active development.